# Why is Duff halal and dhol Haram?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, music

Why is Duff halal and dhol Haram in Islam,Duff and dhol is almost same?Duff is also a musical instrument,isn't it?so,why is it halal and other musical instruments are Haram?

Comment: What is dhol (picture /description)? Duff is clearly mentioned in a hadith.

Comment: Dhol means drum

Answer (score 1):

**Daff is very slighter form of dhol**

Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “There will be among my ummah people who will regard adultery, silk, alcohol and musical instruments as permissible.”

This hadeeth indicates that all musical instruments are haraam, including the daff.

However daff is very slighter form of dhol and at only three situations it was allowed which are:
Eid, weddings, and when one who has been away returns.

The theme here is we should refrain from these as much as possible and slight daff can be allowed in limited situations.

Comment: did prophet (s.a) explicitly allow duff by saying its name ?

Comment: Not explicitly allowed but did not stopped its use at his migration to Madina. If something happened in front of him (s.a) and he didn't stop it then that thing is considered permissible.

Comment: currently music is electronically generated which is not present in prophet(s.a) time, so we can consider it is allowed, as he didn't prohibit it.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, prophet (s.a) didn't explicitly mention the musical instruments that are allowed and that are not allowed. Also, he didn't mention in which all situations any musical instrument(s) can be used. (like in Eid, weddings..) . These rulings are created by later scholars who go through hadiths and when they see a particular instrument being used in a particular situation, they say that instrument is allowed in that situation. Problem is not all situations and instruments get recorded in the hadith and we cannot say all other instruments and situations it is forbidden. Like in modern world music is generated electronically and we have them in our ring tones, calling bells, computer start up/shut down etc. We cannot categorically say all this are forbidden (haraam) because it is not mentioned in hadith.

We should be very careful when declaring something as forbidden or allowed (haraam or halaal)

> But say not - for any false thing that your tongues may put forth,-
> "This is lawful, and this is forbidden," so as to ascribe false things
> to Allah. For those who ascribe false things to Allah, will never
> prosper. [Quran 16:116](https://quran.com/an-nahl/116)